# Automatic conversion of contiguous container type of contigous container types into a another generic "contiguous container type view"

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, implicit-conversion, template-argument-deduction

I have the following code [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGErqSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIACsZqQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BeqnpjgIhYZEsMXHxGraY9oUMQgRMxATZPn5cAXaYDpkNTQTFEdGxCUkKjc2tuZ0TA6FDZSOVAJS2qF7EyOwcJhoAguYAzKHI3lgA1CaHbk7jxJisV9i7B2bHDKdeF1duTcRMAE8ni8jiczphLtcAG7dIjEYH7UEfcGQtwKZKGBGvd6fb7XZDjfCCJ6XRFvMFfCE/O6hYBYl4ETAsZIGRmoggA5KMVgQgAqWLQDHGmFUyWI5yYXiI5w5XIA%2Bsw2BBlpcAOxWfbnLXnQkgEA0oxyqF4TAAd3OiswpHOYswNFU1oUXio9quGuxeCoWCo5zlctOhmAfpe2otPMhABFfXLlAAlbC83kATTlADE5OE3LyAJIAeXCwcO7q1tvtkcuZjMkulsswCp5ysu8QsvPL5jMbpDOudZauUfbJniEYHRZBbxqnvO3vm6AgfoA4uE5G4/csu1rLeW/XGE8m0xms3mC3LO5qbfde4d%2B5XBcLReLq6gZZy65bG4OLKbCAhzq2%2BxWO1HM8nRdPBVDbStB2HSCgOxCcfWnMJZzlABZIQVwANWwWM1zPDdw3/P100zIRs3nQti21UswIgqspSfP1kCwU5n3lS0fhHSitRAy9r0A7AIChVA8HQNcYPdI5XE9dcwzYAA6e4WFQGE5Wo1QIDUuT0gAL0wZU11g0NLQUpllLrHiwIgCzVC0vBdP0089lDe4CA2BhZMwRyTFVYd9kZZlWSpa5a03flDmefZBS2ZICHODxBDwYAvHWBR4saeZxX/e4AEcvDwe4FHOCBWwIFVvK4mU5PQJhGmVRzQwIWz7IMiSfK8vymRZGrPOCl9QpJF47i8Bxz1QVQgXVGTQwazrAp%2BELwwwga8OmsUxoBCBzlvWKMIrAA2c4oXOFUGFQEVooIKbpuukBzhYOUdL0rUoSavSVVwpzrvOa17pi4hNpe6raveq6tXK7zfIOREVt1fU7LrWL7set1SU%2BrVtt/AAqO7VIIeEi1RiHHP8rrGXmvrFqxNbxogDHdvMPaoROs7VAu84AFoSWpoFeq5TcML1KExC8BGX2BWCGVm7qfjSxLkq8VLZCYDLf2WvZQli/hUFpgRxlG8afjC54zAOkm10m/YXLc84uBRkE2uh9XBDu5WGDqi20Z1Ah0EF2ESGpb3fYcf3rg18XsEO7p2s9x8ZU6uUNHLLWfmY2ha0E7plkF4XRa5J4M%2BQFqZNjkm5S4ctuYLlrzgAehr00SAAa0KphCo11xMHQGTYbQKVUR%2BVjXx5FPujTl8IFLrgDIEsrrgH2HXFoO2VpL%2BOzCT1BtZhQuUbr9AzoUBgwA4WK0GZOhMDkwmVqt4h3I0LyfI4VZaE4eJeD8DgtFIVBODcaxrA6nWJsKkbweCkAIJoZ%2BqxG4gEkKqOSAAOQ4ZhEEAE5EFcFVG8N4qo9r6E4JID%2BUCf6cF4AoEAVRIFf2fqQOAsAYCIBQKgc%2B9AyAUB1qwkYwAuCHACFgY0WwMImlNLmPmnBwE0DTrEChEAogkKiKEJoAIJG8EUcwYgAJcxRG0LCVRpAz5sEELmBgtAVE0NIFgFggZxAWPwPcHoMIKEWJFN0KU2xv7t1fhY2geAoj/E0R4LAJC8Z4BYKo1YVADDAAUMIs0YjGD6P4IIEQYh2BSBkIIRQKh1AWN0AEAwRgUAAMsPoPxFDICrFQDFTIzj2aEj7KYSw1gzDfy6D0ZwEBXBTHaIEBg6BBilHKHkNIGQBA9JGQUTIgzhhxE6DUWEvRZgTPmbUJZ/QZmLDmbYZZng2h6HGBs%2BYQyRhTzWBsLYEgX5v2IRY3%2BHBziqEQXtdme1JDnGAMgZANtDhyXLhAXAhASAVj4csXg1CtDLBgQkKo3iiGkHCZUUgn9v73PIZQiBUDVj0KYesAgyQpTkBcPgOEIk9DJOEKIcQGSKXZLUCQ/JpBTT/GSBEghHB37IpIfc3MUoCWxVQD6J5Ly3kfK%2BT8v5RUPBcMymAsFmKaFQtIAgB4WA4jKnZfCxFVQUW8DRbYDFELoGkFgYkP5e1VRcA0FwRBZg8F4LeNIbxhxbmorIQqyF1yOBmF4OEq1OruXuqNUqmExB0jOEkEAA%3D%3D%3D):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <span>
#include <cstdint> 
#include <string>

template <typename T>
constexpr auto type_name() {
    std::string_view name, prefix, suffix;
#ifdef __clang__
    name = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
  prefix = "auto type_name() [T = ";
  suffix = "]";
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    name = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
  prefix = "constexpr auto type_name() [with T = ";
  suffix = "]";
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    name = __FUNCSIG__;
    prefix = "auto __cdecl type_name<";
    suffix = ">(void)";
#endif
    name.remove_prefix(prefix.size());
    name.remove_suffix(suffix.size());
    return name;
}
template <typename T>
concept ContiguousContainer = requires (T t) {
    t.data();
    t.size();
};

template<typename T> 
struct proxy{
            template<typename V> 
        proxy( const V & v ) noexcept
                : m_size(  v.size() )
        , m_ptr( v.data() )
        {}


    std::size_t m_size; 
    const T* m_ptr; 
};
template<typename V>
proxy(const V &v) noexcept -> proxy<typename V::value_type>;

template<ContiguousContainer T> 
int foo(const proxy<T>& temp){
return 1; 
}

int main(){
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec;

    auto temp_0 = foo<decltype(vec)::value_type>(vec);
    auto temp_1 = proxy(vec); //works as intended
    std::cout << type_name<decltype(temp_1)>() << std::endl; 
    auto temp_2 = foo(vec); //doesn't compile. 

    return 0;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get the last line

```
auto temp_2 = foo(vec);
```

to work.  I'm trying to get `vec` of type `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` to coerce into `proxy<std::vector<int>>` in the function.  Ultimately I want foo to take any *container of containers* but specifically coarse them into my type, `proxy`, which in my actual code has other benefits (can take single values, and initializer lists as well, hence why I want it into that type).  Right now I can, with out templates, simply use the constructor to convert (temp_1) but I cannot do so with a function.  I'd like to have a function that can take any container (with `.data()` and `.size()` as members) as a parameter and automatically convert it into a `proxy` type.  But I get the following error:

```
x86-64 gcc 13.1
x86-64 gcc 13.1
-std=c++20
123
<Compilation failed>

# For more information see the output window
x86-64 gcc 13.1 - 1753ms
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:61:22: error: no matching function for call to 'foo(std::vector<std::vector<int> >&)'
   61 |     auto temp_2 = foo(vec); //doesn't compile.
      |                   ~~~^~~~~
<source>:51:5: note: candidate: 'template<class T>  requires  ContiguousContainer<T> int foo(const proxy<T>&)'
   51 | int foo(const proxy<T>& temp){
      |     ^~~
<source>:51:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:61:22: note:   'std::vector<std::vector<int> >' is not derived from 'const proxy<T>'
   61 |     auto temp_2 = foo(vec); //doesn't compile.
      |                   ~~~^~~~~
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:61:22: error: no matching function for call to 'foo(std::vector<std::vector<int> >&)'
   61 |     auto temp_2 = foo(vec); //doesn't compile.
      |                   ~~~^~~~~
<source>:51:5: note: candidate: 'template<class T>  requires  ContiguousContainer<T> int foo(const proxy<T>&)'
   51 | int foo(const proxy<T>& temp){
      |     ^~~
<source>:51:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:61:22: note:   'std::vector<std::vector<int> >' is not derived from 'const proxy<T>'
   61 |     auto temp_2 = foo(vec); //doesn't compile.
      |                   ~~~^~~~~
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

Is there a way for me to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is this (probably in place of your current implementation of `foo`, which seems to serve no purpose):

```
template<typename T> requires ContiguousContainer <T>
auto foo(const T& temp){
    return proxy (temp);
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XvcLsztvmWryFFYA)

---

With reference to OP's comments below, the desired behaviour can be obtained by modifying the `ContiguousContainer` concept (which is now not well named) as follows:

```
template <typename T>
concept ContiguousContainer = requires (T t) {
    t.data();
    t.size();
    t.data ()->data ();
    t.data ()->size ();
};
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DEo72t9PCCe9aoMm)

Or even:

```
template <typename T>
concept ContiguousContainer = requires (T t) {
    t.data ()->data ();
    t.data ()->size ();
};
```

Hehe

Comment: I had to edit my code (I forgot to use ContiguousContainer, hence why it was there), but my original intent was not to just require the first value to be a contiguous container, but to require the value *inside* to also be a contiguous container.  As in, I don't want to match against *other things* that aren't nested like this (no std::vector<int> for example).  And I want it to automatically coarse to proxy inside the arguments.

Comment: to add, I know how to make a concept that requires a type to be nested, but I don't know how to force said type into my proxy type *in the parameters of the function*.  If I don't do it there, I have to duplicate the function many times, or I'm forced to use a "make_proxy" function to handle that instead.